# How Can I Programmatically Add A Binding to CXF Client Code?

Tags: ant, cxf

I am writing an ANT Task that tries to create a proxy for a CXF Web Service like below:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(ProjectApi.class);
factory.setAddress("http://sasdk1/protex-sdk/v5_0/project");
ProjectApi projectApi = (ProjectApi)factory.create();
```

If I run it as a Main method in Eclipse, it runs fine.

However if I try to run as ANT task, it always fails with the following error:

```
org.apache.cxf.BusException:
    No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/ registered
```

How can I programmatically add this binding to the above code?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://logicsector.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-create-a-wsdl-first-soap-client-in-java-with-cxf-and-maven/), the cxf.xml file needs to be in the classpath of the client, in this case Ant.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that does not require placing the cxf.xml file under the Ant lib directory.

```
URL wsdlURL = null;

try {
wsdlURL = new URL("http://sasdk1/protex-sdk/v5_0/project?wsdl");
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(-1);
}

QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(
            "urn:protex.company.com:sdk:v5.0:project",
            "ProjectApiService");
Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);

ProjectApi projectApi = service.getPort(ProjectApi.class);
```